# if shows that numbers cCur(x) and cDbl(x) not equal when x ends with .55555

Tags: vbscript

Here is sample code

```
Dim sPrice : sPrice = "34,55555"

MsgBox(cCur(sPrice))
MsgBox(cDbl(sPrice))

If cCur(sPrice) = cDbl(sPrice) Then
  MsgBox("+")
End If
```

When you take as sPrice another number that don't ends with exactly .55555 all works as expected. How to handle this situation?

Comment: cCur is a conversion to currency datatype which is to 4 decimal places. You have 5 decimal places therefore the number is rounding. There is no simple answer to your question about how to equate cCur() to cDbl() when rounding is needed. You would have to explain more about the use case.

Answer (score 1):

*It's not a bug, it's a feature*?

**Short answer**: the described discrepancy has **no good solution** as `Round()` function does not hold declared ["*round to even*" rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx(v=vs.84).aspx).

[Comparison Operators (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx) reference is too rough and brief: *if both expressions are numeric then perform a numeric comparison*. Nothing about implicit conversions in case of different numeric subtypes, nothing about rounding. 

Analogously, [Conversion Functions reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk3zc840(vs.85).aspx) says something about (implicit) rounding half in case of `CInt()` but nothing in case of `CCur()`. 
Therefore, let's try performing all necessary conversions and roundings explicitly.

**The first attempt**.  Although `cCur(Round( cDbl(sPrice),4)) = Round( cDbl(sPrice),4)` comparison seems to be very close, `Round()` keeps giving wrong `34,5555` instead of `34,5556`. Moreover, that laborious and hungus code (see below at the very end) covers only special cases. Therefore, let's write as far as possible *generally true* script.

**Proof that `Round()` function does not hold declared "*round to even*" rule**:

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' VB Script Document: rounding Double / Currency
'
' Synopsis
'     Checks whether "round to even" rule always holds.
'
' Description
'     Shows some "slope discontinuity" points where "round to even" rule fails
'     and where returns to right behaviour.
'
' Parameters
'     Optional positional (variant subtype)
'
'   #1 (long): fractional part to test (as integer without decimal point)
'        if not numeric or not present then variable strFract defaults to 55555   
' 
'   #2 (any): way of conversion values to Currency subtype, variable booFromStr 
'        if not present (label FAL) then  from Double as CCur( CDbl( sPrice))
'        else (label TRU, results are less pompous) from String as CCur( sPrice)
'
' Usage examples (all with pretty spectacular results)
'
'     cscript 40793437.vbs
'     cscript 40793437.vbs 12335
'     cscript 40793437.vbs 12345
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim sPrice, nn, ii, strVal, dblVal, curVal, curLav, strCur, booFromStr _
  , strTailNowN, strTailLast, strTailCurN, strTailCurL, sDecPoint _
  , strValChange, strCurChange, strResult, strResCur, arrParams, strFract _
  , strFractNn, sAux, strFromStr          ', numChangesVal, numChangesCur

Set arrParams = WScript.Arguments
booFromStr = ( arrParams.Count > 1 )
strFromStr = UCase( Left( Cstr( booFromStr), 3))
strFract = "55555"
If arrParams.Count > 0 Then
  sAux = CStr( arrParams(0))
  If IsNumeric( sAux) Then strFract = Right( strFract & CStr( Abs( CLng(sAux))), 5)
End If
sDecPoint = Mid( FormatNumber( 0.1, 1, true, false, -2), 2, 1)
strResult = "" : strResCur = ""
For nn = 3 To 5
  strFractNn = sDecPoint & Right( strFract, nn)
  sAux = vbTab & "Round(0." & Mid( strFractNn, 2) & "," & CStr( nn-1) & ")="
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & strFromStr _
      & "   Double round change /    Currency round status" & sAux _
      & CStr( Round( CDbl( "0" & strFractNn), nn-1))
  strResCur = strResCur & vbNewLine & strFromStr _
      & " Currency round change /      Double round status" & sAux
  If Not booFromStr Then
      strResCur = strResCur & CStr( Round( CCur( CDbl( "0" & strFractNn)), nn-1)) 
  Else
      strResCur = strResCur & CStr( Round( CCur(     ( "0" & strFractNn)), nn-1))
  End If
  strTailLast = "" : strTailCurL = ""
  'numChangesVal = 0
  'numChangesCur = 0
  For ii = -140000 to 140000
    If ii < 0 Then
        sPrice = "-" & CStr( Abs( ii + 1) ) & strFractNn
    Else
        sPrice = CStr( ii) & strFractNn
    End If
    dblVal = CDbl( sPrice) 
    strVal = Right( Space(18) _
        & FormatNumber( Round( dblVal, nn-1), nn-1, true, false, -2), 18)
    strTailNowN = Right(strVal,1)
    If strTailLast = strTailNowN Then sAux = " == " Else sAux = " -> " 
    strValChange= strTailLast & sAux & strTailNowN
    If Not booFromStr Then
      curVal = Round( CCur( dblVal), nn-1)
      curLav = curVal
      If nn = 5 Then curLav = CCur( dblVal)
      If Not (curLav = curVal) Then MsgBox curLav & vbCrLf & curVal
    Else
      curVal = Round( CCur( sPrice), nn-1)
      curLav = curVal
      If nn = 5 Then curLav = CCur( sPrice)
      If Not (curLav = curVal) Then MsgBox curLav & vbCrLf & curVal
    End If
    strCur = Right( Space(18) & FormatNumber( curVal, nn-1, true, false, -2), 18)
    strTailCurN = Right( strCur, 1)
    If strTailCurL = strTailCurN Then sAux = " == " Else sAux = " -> " 
    strCurChange= strTailCurL & sAux & strTailCurN
    If Not( strTailCurL = strTailCurN) Then
      'numChangesCur = numChangesCur + 1
      If Not (strTailCurL = "") Then 
        strResCur = strResCur & vbNewLine _
          & strCur & " " & strCurChange & " /" & strVal & " " & strValChange
      End If
      strTailCurL = strTailCurN
    End If
    If Not( strTailLast = strTailNowN) Then
      'numChangesVal = numChangesVal + 1
      If Not (strTailLast = "") Then 
        strResult = strResult & vbNewLine _
          & strVal & " " & strValChange & " /" & strCur & " " & strCurChange
      End If
      strTailLast = strTailNowN
    End If
    'If ( numChangesVal > 20 ) or ( numChangesCur > 20 ) Then Exit For 
  Next
Next
strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & strResCur
Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit
```

**Output** is tabbed for easier interpretation and shows that the OP's assumption *"When you take as sPrice another number that don't ends with exactly .55555 <strike>all works as expected</strike>"* is wrong:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\40793437.vbs 12345

FAL   Double round change /    Currency round status    Round(0.345,2)=0,34
           -327,35 4 -> 5 /           -327,34 4 == 4
           -255,34 5 -> 4 /           -255,34 4 == 4
             -9,35 4 -> 5 /             -9,34 4 == 4
             -7,34 5 -> 4 /             -7,34 4 == 4
             -2,35 4 -> 5 /             -2,34 4 == 4
             -1,34 5 -> 4 /             -1,34 4 == 4
              2,35 4 -> 5 /              2,34 4 == 4
              3,34 5 -> 4 /              3,34 4 == 4
              8,35 4 -> 5 /              8,34 4 == 4
             10,34 5 -> 4 /             10,34 4 == 4
            256,35 4 -> 5 /            256,34 4 == 4
            328,34 5 -> 4 /            328,34 4 == 4
FAL   Double round change /    Currency round status    Round(0.2345,3)=0,234
       -67 108,235 4 -> 5 /       -67 108,234 4 == 4
       -65 535,234 5 -> 4 /       -65 535,234 4 == 4
        -8 388,235 4 -> 5 /        -8 388,234 4 == 4
        -8 191,234 5 -> 4 /        -8 191,234 4 == 4
          -261,235 4 -> 5 /          -261,234 4 == 4
          -255,234 5 -> 4 /          -255,234 4 == 4
           256,235 4 -> 5 /           256,234 4 == 4
           262,234 5 -> 4 /           262,234 4 == 4
         8 192,235 4 -> 5 /         8 192,234 4 == 4
         8 389,234 5 -> 4 /         8 389,234 4 == 4
        65 536,235 4 -> 5 /        65 536,234 4 == 4
        67 109,234 5 -> 4 /        67 109,234 4 == 4
FAL   Double round change /    Currency round status    Round(0.12345,4)=0,1234
     -131 071,1234 5 -> 4 /     -131 071,1234 5 -> 4
         -838,1235 4 -> 5 /         -838,1235 5 == 5
         -511,1234 5 -> 4 /         -511,1234 5 -> 4
          512,1235 4 -> 5 /          512,1235 4 -> 5
          839,1234 5 -> 4 /          839,1235 5 == 5
      131 072,1235 4 -> 5 /      131 072,1235 4 -> 5

FAL Currency round change /      Double round status    Round(0.345,2)=0,34
FAL Currency round change /      Double round status    Round(0.2345,3)=0,234
FAL Currency round change /      Double round status    Round(0.12345,4)=0,1235
     -131 071,1234 5 -> 4 /     -131 071,1234 5 -> 4
       -8 191,1235 4 -> 5 /       -8 191,1234 4 == 4
         -511,1234 5 -> 4 /         -511,1234 5 -> 4
         -127,1235 4 -> 5 /         -127,1234 4 == 4
          -63,1234 5 -> 4 /          -63,1234 4 == 4
          -15,1235 4 -> 5 /          -15,1234 4 == 4
           16,1234 5 -> 4 /           16,1234 4 == 4
           64,1235 4 -> 5 /           64,1234 4 == 4
          128,1234 5 -> 4 /          128,1234 4 == 4
          512,1235 4 -> 5 /          512,1235 4 -> 5
        8 192,1234 5 -> 4 /        8 192,1234 4 == 4
      131 072,1235 4 -> 5 /      131 072,1235 4 -> 5
```

**Output** part II shows different *slope discontinuity* points for slightly  another fractional part:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\40793437.vbs 12335

FAL   Double round change /    Currency round status    Round(0.335,2)=0,34
        -10 485,33 4 -> 3 /        -10 485,34 4 == 4
         -8 191,34 3 -> 4 /         -8 191,34 4 == 4
           -327,33 4 -> 3 /           -327,34 4 == 4
           -255,34 3 -> 4 /           -255,34 4 == 4
            -81,33 4 -> 3 /            -81,34 4 == 4
            -63,34 3 -> 4 /            -63,34 4 == 4
             64,33 4 -> 3 /             64,34 4 == 4
             82,34 3 -> 4 /             82,34 4 == 4
            256,33 4 -> 3 /            256,34 4 == 4
            328,34 3 -> 4 /            328,34 4 == 4
          8 192,33 4 -> 3 /          8 192,34 4 == 4
         10 486,34 3 -> 4 /         10 486,34 4 == 4
FAL   Double round change /    Currency round status    Round(0.2335,3)=0,234
       -16 776,233 4 -> 3 /       -16 776,234 4 == 4
       -16 383,234 3 -> 4 /       -16 383,234 4 == 4
        -2 096,233 4 -> 3 /        -2 096,234 4 == 4
        -2 047,234 3 -> 4 /        -2 047,234 4 == 4
          -130,233 4 -> 3 /          -130,234 4 == 4
          -127,234 3 -> 4 /          -127,234 4 == 4
           128,233 4 -> 3 /           128,234 4 == 4
           131,234 3 -> 4 /           131,234 4 == 4
         2 048,233 4 -> 3 /         2 048,234 4 == 4
         2 097,234 3 -> 4 /         2 097,234 4 == 4
        16 384,233 4 -> 3 /        16 384,234 4 == 4
        16 777,234 3 -> 4 /        16 777,234 4 == 4
FAL   Double round change /    Currency round status    Round(0.12335,4)=0,1234
         -209,1233 4 -> 3 /         -209,1233 3 == 3
         -127,1234 3 -> 4 /         -127,1234 3 -> 4
          -26,1233 4 -> 3 /          -26,1233 3 == 3
          -15,1234 3 -> 4 /          -15,1234 3 -> 4
           16,1233 4 -> 3 /           16,1233 4 -> 3
           27,1234 3 -> 4 /           27,1233 3 == 3
          128,1233 4 -> 3 /          128,1233 4 -> 3
          210,1234 3 -> 4 /          210,1233 3 == 3

FAL Currency round change /      Double round status    Round(0.335,2)=0,34
FAL Currency round change /      Double round status    Round(0.2335,3)=0,234
FAL Currency round change /      Double round status    Round(0.12335,4)=0,1234
     -131 071,1233 4 -> 3 /     -131 071,1234 4 == 4
      -65 535,1234 3 -> 4 /      -65 535,1234 4 == 4
      -16 383,1233 4 -> 3 /      -16 383,1234 4 == 4
       -2 047,1234 3 -> 4 /       -2 047,1234 4 == 4
       -1 023,1233 4 -> 3 /       -1 023,1234 4 == 4
         -511,1234 3 -> 4 /         -511,1234 4 == 4
         -255,1233 4 -> 3 /         -255,1234 4 == 4
         -127,1234 3 -> 4 /         -127,1234 3 -> 4
          -31,1233 4 -> 3 /          -31,1234 4 == 4
          -15,1234 3 -> 4 /          -15,1234 3 -> 4
           -3,1233 4 -> 3 /           -3,1234 4 == 4
           -1,1234 3 -> 4 /           -1,1234 4 == 4
            2,1233 4 -> 3 /            2,1234 4 == 4
            4,1234 3 -> 4 /            4,1234 4 == 4
           16,1233 4 -> 3 /           16,1233 4 -> 3
           32,1234 3 -> 4 /           32,1234 4 == 4
          128,1233 4 -> 3 /          128,1233 4 -> 3
          256,1234 3 -> 4 /          256,1234 4 == 4
          512,1233 4 -> 3 /          512,1234 4 == 4
        1 024,1234 3 -> 4 /        1 024,1234 4 == 4
        2 048,1233 4 -> 3 /        2 048,1234 4 == 4
       16 384,1234 3 -> 4 /       16 384,1234 4 == 4
       65 536,1233 4 -> 3 /       65 536,1234 4 == 4
      131 072,1234 3 -> 4 /      131 072,1234 4 == 4

==>
```

For the sake of completeness, here's my first attempt script and result:

```
option explicit
On Error GoTo 0
Dim sR: sR = Wscript.ScriptName

check ("34,12355")
check ("34,55555")

Wscript.Echo sR
Wscript.Quit

Sub check (sPrice)
  Dim bMatch
  bMatch = ( cCur(sPrice) = cDbl(sPrice) )
  sR = sR & vbNewLine & Cstr( bMatch) & Space( 1+Abs( bMatch)) & " a cCur = cDbl " _
          & cCur(sPrice) & " = " & cDbl(sPrice)
  bMatch = ( cCur(sPrice) = Round( cDbl(sPrice), 4) )
  sR = sR & vbNewLine & Cstr( bMatch) & Space( 1+Abs( bMatch)) & " b cCur = cDbl " _
          & cCur(sPrice) & " = " & Round( cDbl(sPrice), 4)
  bMatch = ( Round( cCur(sPrice), 4) = cDbl(sPrice) )
  sR = sR & vbNewLine & Cstr( bMatch) & Space( 1+Abs( bMatch)) & " c cCur = cDbl " _
          & Round( cCur(sPrice), 4) & " = " & cDbl(sPrice)
  bMatch = ( Round( cCur(sPrice), 4) = Round( cDbl(sPrice),4) )
  sR = sR & vbNewLine & Cstr( bMatch) & Space( 1+Abs( bMatch)) & " d cCur = cDbl " _
          & Round( cCur(sPrice), 4) & " = " & Round( cDbl(sPrice), 4)
  bMatch = ( cCur(Round( cDbl(sPrice),4)) = Round( cDbl(sPrice),4) )
  sR = sR & vbNewLine & Cstr( bMatch) & Space( 1+Abs( bMatch)) & " ? cCur = cDbl " _
          & cCur(Round( cDbl(sPrice),4)) & " = " & Round( cDbl(sPrice), 4)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SO\40793437a.vbs
40793437a.vbs
True   a cCur = cDbl 34,1236 = 34,12355
True   b cCur = cDbl 34,1236 = 34,1236
True   c cCur = cDbl 34,1236 = 34,12355
True   d cCur = cDbl 34,1236 = 34,1236
True   ? cCur = cDbl 34,1236 = 34,1236
False  a cCur = cDbl 34,5556 = 34,55555
False  b cCur = cDbl 34,5556 = 34,5555
False  c cCur = cDbl 34,5556 = 34,55555
False  d cCur = cDbl 34,5556 = 34,5555
True   ? cCur = cDbl 34,5555 = 34,5555
```

Comment: Great answer, talk about going the extra mile!